# Using A Variable prompt and a filter statement for a column value

Tags: variables, obiee

I am working with an analysis that uses a filter statement to run a calculation on the data. The user wants to be able to change between two different values to view different combinations of scenarios. I keep getting a syntax error on the formula and cant figure out where I am going wrong.

```
((FILTER(IFNULL("INDRATES"."Client Site Wrap Rate", 0)USING ("Scenario"."Scenario - Default" IN @{"Scenario_1"}{'Forecast'})))-(FILTER(IFNULL("INDRATES"."Client Site Wrap Rate", 0)USING ("Scenario"."Scenario - Default" IN @{"Scenario_2"}{'Plan'}))))
```

I have been going over and over it and not sure where I am going wrong, any help would be awesome.

Updated code:

```
(FILTER(IFNULL("INDRATES"."Client Site Wrap Rate",0) USING ("Scenario"."Scenario - Default" =  @{Scenario_1}{"Scenario"."Scenario - Default"})))-(FILTER(IFNULL("INDRATES"."Client Site Wrap Rate",0) USING ("Scenario"."Scenario - Default" =  @{Scenario_2}{"Scenario"."Scenario - Default"})))
```

Comment: Hi, try to put the single quote for the variable like this: 
'@{Scenario_2}{Plan}'

Comment: I thought that was only for strings, I have managed to get it so it is not throwing a syntax error but it is still coming up with 0

Comment: So it means that the value is null, and your formula cast the null value into 0. You can check the part of the formula again if it should return a specific value.

Answer (score 1):

So I have finally resolved the issue so I figured I would post the full answer, and thanks to those who commented, they had components of the answer. So the initial problem we were running into was the IN section which should have been an = sign to finish the FILTER Expression. Secondly, we did not set the filter for Scenario.Scenario - Default to equal a variable expression. third was we were trying to input a default value for Scenario_1 and Scenario_2 which we didnt need in the dashboard (but it does need to be set in order to view it in the analysis). Last, was as the first comment mentioned it did need a single quote ' around the @{Scenario_1} as it was searching for a text value and not a numeric value. The correct syntax and working code is placed below.

```
((FILTER(IFNULL("INDRATES"."Client Site Wrap Rate",0) USING ("Scenario"."Scenario - Default" =  '@{Scenario_1}')))-(FILTER(IFNULL("INDRATES"."Client Site Wrap Rate",0) USING ("Scenario"."Scenario - Default" =  '@{Scenario_2}'))))
```